# C++: Error C4700 uninitialized local variable “ ” used

Tags: c++

I have written out the code out but I keep getting an error saying:  "Error C4700 uninitalized local variable "zi_saptamana" used.  "Error C4700 uninitialized local variable "dar" used.  I've done If/if-else/else nesting before but I've never ran into this error. I am new to C++ and still learning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int zi_saptamana, a, s, d, f, g, h, j; char dar;

    switch (zi_saptamana)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << " a"; cin >> a;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << " s"; cin >> s;
        break;
    case  3:
        cout << " d"; cin >> d;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "  f"; cin >> f;
    case 5:
        cout << "  g"; cin >> g;
    case 6:
        cout << " h"; cin >> h;
    case 7:
        cout << "  j"; cin >> j;
    default:
        cout << " nu stiu ce zi este aceasta te rog sa alegi o zi de la 1 la 7";
        break;
    }
    cout << " ce zi a saptamanii doresti?";
    cin >> zi_saptamana;
    cout << " doresti sa alegi o alta zi din saptamana ??\n_> ";
    if (dar == 'y' || dar == 'Y');
    {
        main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. I mean it is clear from the code `zi_saptamana` was not initialized before `switch (zi_saptamana)`

Comment: What part of "uninitialized local variable used" is unclear?

Comment: The error message is clear. When `switch (zi_saptamana)`, `zi_saptamana` is not initialized or set, its value is indeterminate.

Comment: Also never call main(). http://stackoverflow.com/a/36363746/487892

Answer (score 2):

You declare `zi_saptamana` as `int`, but immediately after that, without giving it a value (without *initializing* it), you *use* it in the `switch` statement.

Note that the value of `zi_saptamana`, which is a local variable, is undefined (it can be anything) before it is initialized. The same applies to `dar`.

That is what the compiler is telling you.

Note that, as commented, this is undefined behaviour, making the program not a well-formed one anymore and the compiler is free to do what it seems appropriate. In this case (i.e. this compiler), it issues an error.

Simply put (without the "standardese"): It is undefined behaviour: the run of the rest of a program can depend on this variable, and if it is not in a known state, you can't know what will happen. That is why most compilers flag it as an error.

Comment: It's not that it "can be anything", it's that reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour and the program thus has no meaning and the compiler can do anything - including removing the switch completely. You are not giaranteed to just get a random garbage value (although you *might*).

Comment: Well, for all you know or care, it can be anything. That is why using an uninitialized variable was declared as undefined behaviour, ISTM.

Comment: Well, compilers are pretty agressive about exploiting undefined behaviour these days. And it may change other parts of your program as well as a result - you cannot assume that the "undefinedness effects" will be contained to *just* interactions with that one variable. See for example [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633), [this](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) & [this](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: I know what undefined behaviour is and what it means. It could just as well cause WW3 or cause your harddisk to be formatted, as a friend of mine always said.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the variable zi_saptamana to have switch working in your program to do that just put that statement before switch:-

```
scanf("%d",&zi_saptamana);
```

it'll take a Integer value from user and switch will work according to this.